# find values closest to a list of values in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's suppose to have this Pyspark dataframe:

```
x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)
z = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Let's suppose to have this list of values:

```
lst = [10, 20, 30]
```

I would like to retrieve all the **3** (=`len(lst)`) rows of spark_df such that the difference between each value of `lst` and `spark_df.x` is the lowest. I would like to retrieve this three values as a spark dataframe. E.g:

```
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
| 11| 32| 84|
| 22| 12| 38|
| 29| 14| 12|
+---+---+---+
```

In this case:

- `11` is the closest `spark_df.x` value to `10`
- `22` is the closest `spark_df.x` value to `20`
- `29` is the closest `spark_df.x` value to `30`

How can achieve this result in Pyspark 3+?

Note: this is only a toy example and the list of values could be in the order of thousands.

Comment: If you're asking for how to improve existing, working code, you should ask on Code Review. Such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they are opinion-based.

Comment: You included a (in your own words, "bad") solution in your question. So it's unclear what you're asking for if not a "better" solution, but you don't bother to explain what you want in specific, objective terms. What's bad about the solution you provided? What actual, specific metric are you wanting your solution to achieve that it currently false short in? Don't laugh derisively when someone remarks that your question has problems; fix the problems instead.

Comment: You should not assume I am the one who downvoted in the first place, just because I commented. That aside, my second comment just says the same thing as the first comment, just in more detail, doing some of the leg-work of explaining what the [help] says for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments on my own, I propose this solution. At first, I wanted avoid `pandas_udf` function, but, none the less, it seems elegant, pythonic and effective.

**Step 1**:
Create a pandas_udf in order to obtain a list of minimum values:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

bdc_values = sc.broadcast([10, 20, 30])

@pandas_udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def get_x_min(x: pd.Series) -> ArrayType(IntegerType()):
   values = bdc_values.value
   return [x.iloc[(x - v).abs().argmin()] for v in values]
```

**Step 2**:
Apply the pandas_udf to dataframe and collect the values, in this way:

```
mins = spark_df.agg(get_x_min('x')).first()[0]
```

**Step 3**:
Filter the spark_df with `isin` function and then eventually deduplicate:

```
result = spark_df.filter(func.col('x').isin(mins)).dropDuplicates(['x'])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: add columns with the difference of the elements of `lst` and the `x` values to the dataframe:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

diffs = [F.abs(F.col("x") - F.lit(c)).alias(f"diff_{c}") for c in lst]
df_with_diffs = spark_df.select("*", *diffs)
```

```
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
|  x|  y|  z|diff_10|diff_20|diff_30|
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 15| 34| 20|      5|      5|     15|
| 12| 45| 24|      2|      8|     18|
| 86| 49| 13|     76|     66|     56|
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
only showing top 3 rows
```

**Step 2:**
Collect the minimal values for each of the `diff` columns and select the respective rows:

```python
mins=df_with_diffs.select(*[F.min(f"diff_{c}") for c in lst]).first()

filter=" or ".join([f"(diff_{c} = {mins[i]})" for i,c in enumerate(lst)])
df_with_diffs.filter(filter).select(spark_df.columns).show()
```

```
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
| 12| 45| 24|
| 22| 28| 58|
| 27| 96| 36|
+---+---+---+
```

**Step 2 (original answer):** use [min_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#min_by) for each of the newly created columns to find the row with the minimal difference. For each value of `lst` this returns one row. All these rows are then [unioned](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html).

```pytjon
agg_cols = [[F.expr(f"min_by({c}, diff_{val})").alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns] 
  for val in lst]

import functools
result = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a.union(df_with_diffs.agg(*b)), agg_cols[1:], 
          df_with_diffs.agg(*agg_cols[0]))
result.show()
```

Comment: not sure this solution is so efficient. in the toy example i've reported a list of three value, but the real length could be in the order of thousands. what do you think?

Comment: I think you have to execute one aggregation over the whole dataframe per entry of `lst`. But let's wait and see if another answerer finds a better approach

Comment: I changed the second step so that the minimal values are explictly collected and then a normal filter is applied. I  guess that this approach might be faster

Comment: in a sense your proposed solution seems to be similar to mine (just update it in the main post): i use a pandas_udf to retrieve the mins value (without creating a lot of columns) and i use `isin` built-in function to avoid the big filter function you wrote. but still not satisfied